# Поддержка проекта в моем приложении

Tags: android

Здравствуйте наткнулся на интересный способ поддержки проекта (второй скриншот)

[image] [image]

Вопрос заключается в том , как это реализовать. Может кто нибудь скинет ссылку для прочтения информации или пример, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Что значит `способ поддержки проекта`? На картинке нет толком информации. Что будет если нажать на эти элементы? Этот подарок будет отправлен автору приложения, или это можно будет купить?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin добавил фото.

Comment: Так это же обычные покупки в приложении

Comment: @PeterSamokhin я новичок ,было бы хорошо если бы вы скинули ссылку на информацию как это реализовать или пример.

Comment: Готово. Добавил ответ и ссылку на пример.

Comment: Если ответ вас удовлетворяет и решает проблему вопроса, примите его - чуть левее самого ответа находится галочка :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что вы привели в пример - обычные in-app purchasing (покупки в приложении). Вот статья на эту тему: https://habrahabr.ru/post/117944/, и вот еще один пример: https://habrahabr.ru/post/313416/